# how to check traffic in aws hosted website?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I hosted my portfolio(static website using html and css) in aws using E2 instance and route 53 and godaddy domain.Now I want to see how many people saw it.How I can check number of views in my portfolio?
I searched in google but didn't find solution.

Comment: Add Google Analytics script on your website.

Comment: Google Analytics is usually more trouble that it is worth given all the GDPR rules.

Comment: If your site is statically hosted using S3, then you could enable [the logging option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/LoggingWebsiteTraffic.html).

Comment: I did not hosted in s3 . i hosted using windows ec2 instance, IIS

Comment: Ah yes, you did say that. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider hosting your portfolio using S3 Static Website, and Cloudfront (optional), [refer this aws blog](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website)

and coming to your query, if you've any specific use case to use EC2, EC2 doesn't have default configurations to get the access log, that too with specific URLs (your portfolio), you should log invocations somewhere and parse those log files to get different stats like ip_address, device type etc

the above-mentioned stats by default available in both S3 and Cloudfront if you enable logging for that.